# Есть ли эквивалент для SQL Server CURSOR STATIC?

Tags: sql, oracle, cursor

Нужно обрабатыват данные из таблицы, перебирая циклом текущие записи с помощью курсора. Вновь добавленные записи во время работы с курсором не должны быть видны в цикле.

В SQL Server использую для этого [CURSOR STATIC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), который делает снапшот результата запроса на момент времени открытия курсора. Но не могу найти эквивалент в Oracle.

Есть ли какой-либо способ добиться этого?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Equivalent for SQL Server CURSOR STATIC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69054758) от участника [@Xayris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13353523/xayris)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/69054758

Answer (score 3):

Ожидаемое поведение курсора в вопросе, это поведение в СУБД Oracle по умолчанию.

Результат запроса определяется состоянием данных на момент открытия курсора, и не меняется, пока открыт курсор. Это называется **Statement-Level Read Consistency** (согласованность чтения на уровне запроса) и описывается [в одноименной гл. книги Database Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/cncpt/data-concurrency-and-consistency.html#GUID-6A252EAE-7900-47DC-BD6A-D5376A6B7608).

Пример, на котором видно, что курсор не видит изменений таблицы, которые были произведенны после его открытия:

```
create table t (val) as select 1 from dual;

var rc refcursor
var ret refcursor

exec open :rc for select * from t

update t set val=val*10;
insert into t values (2);

declare tab sys.odciNumberList;
begin
    fetch :rc bulk collect into tab;
    open :ret for select * from table (tab);
end;
/
print ret

COLUMN_VALUE
------------
           1
```

Только новый курсор увидит изменения:

```
exec open :rc for select * from t
print rc

       VAL
----------
        10
         2
```

Comment: >>Только новый курсор, открытый в этой же транзакции....
не сессии?

Comment: @NMD Полезное замечание,  вообще-то не играет роли, транзакции или сессии. Курсор при открытии увидит зафиксированные изменения в чужих сессиях и все изменения в своей сессии. Любые изменения после его открытия, неважно в какой сессии, курсор не увидит